# TypeError: data.map is not a function creando un Header Dropdown con Recat

Tags: reactjs, fetch, headers, useeffect

Estoy creando un Header con React donde cuando entre en el Elemento se puedan ver mas opciones el problema es que me aparece este Problema de `TypeError: data.map`
Dejo aqui el codigo del Header

```
import UseFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";
import "../../styles/header.css"
import Dropdown from "../atomos/Dropdown";
const Header = () => {
    const dataOne = UseFetch("/header_items")

    return(
        <>
        <header className="Header">
        <div className="container_img navbar">
            <NavLink to="/">
                <img src="https://www.starbucks.com.mx/media/logo_tcm54-366_w1024_n.png" alt="starbucks" />
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className="nav_items">
            {
                dataOne && 
                dataOne.map(item=> (
                    <li key={item.key} className="nav-item">
                        <Link to={item.to}>{item.title}</Link>
                    </li>
                ))
            }
        </div>
        </header>
        {
            dataOne ?
            dataOne.map(({
                to2
            })=>(
                <Dropdown 
                    url={to2}
                />
                ))
                : <h2>Cragando...</h2>
        }
        </>
        )
}



export default Header;
```

En el componente anterior se utiliza el Dropdown donde a este le estoy pasando una url que de esa url es de donde estoy sacando los datos o las url´s del los subMenus puse el if por que algunos objetos no tienen hijos
Dejo aqui la linea de codigo donde esta el problema especificamente me aparece en la linea 15

````
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { useState } from "react"

const Dropdown = ({
   url
}) => {

   const data = UseFetch(url)
   console.log(url)
   const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false); 
   if(data){
       return(
           <>
           <ul 
           className={dropdown ? "services-submenu": "services-submenu"}  
           onClick={() => setDropdown(true)}
           >
           
               {
                   data.map(item => (
                       <li key = {item.id} >
                           <Link className="link_li" to={`${item.onePart}${item.twoPart}`}
                               onClick={() => setDropdown(false)}
                           >{item.title}</Link>
                       </li>
                   )) 
               }
           </ul>
           </>
       )
   }else{
       return false
   }
   
}

export default Dropdown ```
````

Comment: Ese tipo de error suele suceder cuando intentas hacerle un `.map` a una variable que no es un array. ¿Estás seguro que lo que está dentro de `data` es un array? Puedes verificarlo haciendo un `console.log(typeof(data))`.